# SQLite saves float values in integer

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm using System.Data.SQLite to save data to database. In table there are 2 columns defined as float. However when I save data to DB it saves only integer part.

12.2345 => 12
11.5324 => 11
(I don't know how exactly it rounds, it just rounds)

Yes I'm sure I'm using floats in my application, and I'm sure that CommandText contains float numbers NOT integer.

Comment: what is your table schema, how are you saving and retrieving the data?

Comment: nevermind I actually solving it by using REAL data type

Comment: My sqlite3 2.6.0 in 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] returns floats from an integer field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be using floats in your application, but you also need to make sure the table entry in the SQLite database has been explicitly declared to be that REAL type.

Answer (score -1):

There is no support for floats as build-in type. Use TEXT instead.

Comment: My bad: REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.